# BeanCreation exception when using @MockBean

Tags: java, junit, mockito, javabeans, autowired

In my test class I m using @mockbean annotation

```
@MockBean
SOAPConnector soapConnector;
```

The bean soapConnector works fine is my development but it gives me bean creation exception in test env.

> Error creating bean with name 'soapConnector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Following is the bean definition

```
@Bean(name="soapConnector")
public SOAPConnector soapConnector(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
  SOAPConnector client = new SOAPConnector();
  client.setDefaultUri("https://ms.cross-
  check.com/ProcessCheck/ProcessCheckSoapImpl.wsdl");
  client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
  client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
  return client;
}
```

Comment: Please add exception stack trace and explain what is `SOAPConnector` class

Comment: You may need to mock the parameter as well.

Comment: @grape_mao you mean to say marshaller ?

Comment: @vipulk10 yes, it's just a guess though.

Comment: thanks everyone, problem solved using @Spy annotation